# the current path ,About.html didn't match any of these in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^About/', views.About,name='About'),
    url(r'^checkout/', views.checkout,name='checkout'),
    url(r'^contact', views.contact,name='contact'),
    url(r'^faqs', views.faqs,name='faqs'),
    url(r'^help', views.help,name='help'),
    url(r'^icons', views.icons,name='icons'),
    url(r'^payment', views.payment,name='payment'),
    url(r'^privacy', views.privacy,name='privacy'),
```

]

The error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/About.html
Using the URLconf defined in shop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, 
in this order: 
admin/ 
^$ [name='index'] 
^about/$ [name='about'] 
^checkout/$ [name='checkout'] 
^contact/$ [name='contact'] 
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$ 
The current path, About.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: I am not sure that you have included this urls file in your root url file and also None of your URLs has the `$` sign at the end. This sign is a regex expression that uses to matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string

Answer (score 3):

This kind of an error could occur from 2 or 3 different scenarios. 
In your case, you seem to put the wrong URL in the browser address bar.

Your correct URL should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/About (as you've written in the URL patterns).

Remember, About.html - is the HTML template you create inside the templates folder. Even though you route to the html page (with a string like: app_name/About.html) - the actual URL in the address bar will be according to what you write in the regex path r'^url_name'. If you write r'^About.html' in url patterns, then  http://127.0.0.1:8000/About.html should work perfectly.

The second scenario (based on my experience) which could produce this type of an error is when you forget to pass the 'request' argument inside the method that defines view of the URL - in the respective views.py file.

You should be having a method named About which would look like this in views.py
    def About(request):
    return render(request,'app_name/About.html')

If you forget to pass argument in the paranthesis of About, this kind of an error could occur.

Finally, if you are using django 2, please start using re_path method to serve regex url patterns. The url method is likely to be depracated in future release.

Refer [re_path documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path).

Answer (score 1):

your URL will not be http://127.0.0.1:8000/About.html it will just be http://127.0.0.1:8000/about (remember urls are case insensitive), this will take you to your view which is named About, in your view you should reference your template in its render (about.html)

have you read the my first Django app https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/ its a great place to start if you are unfamiliar with how django operates

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to hit is not a valid url, you have to hit http://127.0.0.1:8000/About **as written in urls.py**.

You have to understand the difference between urls and html templates, this **About.html** would be used in views while rendering like:

```
return render(request, 'your_app/about.html')
```

And for sure you can write a url if you want like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
url(r'^About.html/', views.About,name='About'),
.
.
]
```

[Check the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

The url which you provide in url ( ) method doesn't contain any suffix of .html

You can goto the about page directly by /About